# Xaml Previewer not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just can't get the XAML-Previewer to work. 
It's always empty:

[image]

**What I tried so far:**

- Renistalled Xamarin completely
- Run Repair on whole VS

Also no Errors or Crashes can be found inside the xamarin logs.

**Environment:**

```
Windows 10 Professional    
Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise    
Xamarin 4.2.1.64 - (NuGet-Version 2.3.2.127)    
No Mac - Connected (Running Android atm)    
JDK 1.8.0_112    
JRE 1.8.0_112    
NDK R13B    
SDK 25.2.3
```

I've searched the xamarin forum and SO for hours but still cannot get it to work.

Anyone found a solution on this ? it drives me crazy...

It would be great to use this feature...

Comment: Might help confirming that your XAML markup is valid in the first place.

Comment: Its an new default content page with a label. There would be some error instead. That is not the case !

Comment: To my knowledge, the Android previewer works only with the latest android version and Xamarin.Forms version. I'll try dig up a reference for this. In the meantime use the iOS previewer.

Comment: Don't i have the latest version ?  I currently got no mac ... So i guess thats impossible... @matthewrdev

Comment: I'll clarify, when your application targets the latest version of Android (7) and Xamarin.Forms (2.2 and above I believe).

Comment: Can you tell me which API Version this is ? I am currently using API Lv 26 I think. I will check that once i get home !

Comment: @matthewrdev I still can't get it working. Even in VS 2017 RC its not working on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the Android SDK build tools API 24 and be sure to have the JDK 1.8 installed. Build your droid project and you will be ready to go.